# npm i react-instagram-embed dependency showing npm error

Tags: npm

All i can see this on my CLI is this. Is this dependency working or not?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE                                  
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! While resolving: instagram-clone@0.1.0      
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2  
npm ERR! node_modules/react  
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:  
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@2.0.0  
npm ERR! node_modules/react-instagram-embed    
npm ERR!   react-instagram-embed@"*" from the root project  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry  
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps  
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.  
npm ERR!
```

Comment: I don't see the question. Please read [how to ask..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before submiting question.

Comment: see this is it ok?

Comment: have you tried `rm -rf package-lock.json ./node_modules && npm i`?

Comment: yes ,still its not working.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example in eg. codesandbox. Without it it's impossible to debug.